# Impacts of configuring IoC Container from code

Tags: inversion-of-control

I currently have a home-made IoC container that I will soon replace with a new one. My home-made IoC container is configured using config files. From what I have read on the net, the ability to "configure from code" seems to be a very popular feature.

I don’t like the idea of having a class that knows every other class in the system in order to setup the IoC Container. Such class would have to be in an assembly that depends on the 80 other assemblies of my project.

Are there best practices on how to organize the code that configures the container?

*I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456839/what-conventions-idioms-patterns-are-you-using-configuring-ioc-containers-using-t). Using conventions and auto-wiring is good when there are patterns in the types to be registered. But I have hundreds of types that are in different assemblies and that don’t have anything in common. How should I organize the code for those?*

Regards,

**Update:** I chose an approach where the code that configures the container is decentralized. Each assembly in my system is given a chance to configure the container. The method at the entry points in my system (many .exe apps, the web app, the web services app and the unit test fixtures are all entry points) are responsible for calling each assembly to let them setup the container. I'm currently implementing that, I' not sure if it is going to be satisfactory. I will post another update soon.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your programming language (I use c#) you might want to look something like Autofac modules: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules